# reduce the size of the table by deleting null values

Tags: c++

i am coding Huffman using C++ , i have an int table (count[26]) to calculate the frequency (now is Full of values). the number of letters using in the text are just 16 , so the rest of the counter table is allocating with 0 , i want to get a pure table without 0 with the size of 16

any function should i use?

here is just an example of the code (i put values on counter[]):

```
int counter[26] = {1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 8, 7, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0};
int frequencies[16]={0};
for (int y=0; y<26 ;y++){
        if (counter[y] != 0){
            frequencies[y]=counter[y];
            cout<<"\n frequency table :  "<< frequencies[y]<<endl; 

}

}
```

Comment: Since this is C++, use `std::remove()`. The algorithm is already written for you.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that you have 11 zeroes which leaves 15 more elements in the first array. Second array has 16 elements which means that after applying the `std::copy_if` the last element in frequencies will be 0.

Comment: @RawN right `1 2 3 5 4 1 10 5 5 8 7 1 4 1 8 0`

Answer (score 2):

[`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) solves this problem exactly.

Pass `std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b), [](int x)->bool{ return x; }` to copy non-zero elements from array `a` to array `b`.

Comment: @SauravSahu As it should, the last 0 in second array is a leftover because the second array has one more element. The OP assumes there are 16 non zero elements in the first array when in fact there are 15.

Comment: Yes right. How someone would know count of `non-zero-number` before deciding size of `b`. Seems impractical. Instead he can start with source `a` size. `copy_if` returns an iterator pointing to the element that follows the last element written in the result sequence. That iterator can be used for trimming/resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Have `counter` and `frequencies` as *std::vector*, so that you can have *iterator* next to the last valid element in `frequencies`, for clean-up/resizing.

```
vector<int> counter = {1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 8, 7, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0};
vector<int> frequencies(counter.size());
auto it = std::copy_if (counter.begin(), counter.end(), frequencies.begin(), 
                    [](int i){return (i > 0);} );

while(it != frequencies.end()){
    frequencies.erase(it);
}
```

> i want to get a pure table without 0 with the size of 16

Your choice of data structure is wrong in that case. It seems you are mapping each character with their respective count, and then you want to filter out the non-existing character's count. You should instead use `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem, i just added an integer as a counter (in table of frequencies from 0 to 15 ), small & simple solution

thank's a lot for your answers & thanks for help

i am just an amateur :)

```
int counter[26] = {1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 8, 7, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0};
int j=0; // 

int frequencies[16]={0};
for (int y=0; y<26 ;y++){

        if (counter[y] != 0 && letters[y] !='0'){
            frequencies[j]=counter[y];
            cout<<"\n tableau frequence :  "<< frequencies[j]<<endl; 
            j++;

}

}
```